# Deserialize XML with HTML Tags

Tags: html, deserialization, xml-deserialization

I'm wondering for a solution to deserialise the values of HTML in a XML Element. 
My Sample XML is given below,

```
<root>
<Element>
<P>This <i>is </i> a sample <B>XML Tag</B><P>
</Element>
<root>
```

I want this "

This *is*  a sample **XML Tag**

" as string. Please suggest me the solution. I cannot add cdata in the XML file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use escape characters:

```
"   &quot;
'   &apos;
<   &lt;
>   &gt;
&   &amp;
```

Full reference:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references

Answer (score 0):

You can use HSharp to deserialize HTML and XML.
HSharp is a library used to analyse markup language like HTML easily and fastly. Install:`Install-Package Obisoft.HSharp`
View in GitHub:[enter link description here](https://github.com/Obisoft2017/HSharp)

The code you want should be like this:

```
        var DeResult = HtmlConvert.DeserializeHtml("<root>...</root>");//fill it
        Console.WriteLine(DeResult["root"]["element"]["p"].Son);
```